# Eclipse checkstyle checks log4j, and I can't make it stop

Tags: eclipse, log4j, checkstyle

I can't find any configuration for the recent tendency of the Eclipse checkstyle plugin (I'm running 5.1.0) to complain about style issues in log4j.property files. It's not in my checkstyle.xml, it doesn't happen when I run checkstyle outside of eclipse, and I don't see an eclipse preference. Is this controllable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, from the checkstyle section of the "project properties", exclude

```
"file from non source directories"
```

If you select that option, it will stop "checking" that properties file.

Or you can click on the list of file types to check, and delete 'properties'.

[alt text http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8035/eclipsecheckstyleexclud.png](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8035/eclipsecheckstyleexclud.png)

Comment: thanks. I still wonder: why doesn't checkstyle.xml have a specific element for this log4j stuff?

Comment: @bmargulies: thanks for the edit. I just added the illustration.